# JAVA : getting back an instance of an object from a class

Tags: java, object, return

I have a problem in returning an instance of an object which is defined inside a class, in the code below I tried to make a `Socket` connection inside of a class which extends `Thread` . the `socket_connect` class:

```
public class socket_connect extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    private OutputStream out;
    private String host;
    private int port;
    socket_connect(String host,int port){
        this.host=host;
        this.port=port;
        this.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            this.socket = new Socket(this.host,this.port);
            this.out=new BufferedOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
            this.out.write("i am here \n\r".getBytes());
            this.out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }
    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }
    public Socket getSocket() {
              return socket;
    }
    public  OutputStream getOut() {
        return out;
    }
}
```

the main class:

```
public class mymain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Socket backsock;
    String backhost;
    int backport;
    String msg ="Second Hi!!!!!";
    socket_connect sc = new socket_connect("127.0.0.1",8080);
    backsock = sc.getSocket();
    backhost = sc.getHost();
    backport = sc.getPort();
    System.out.println(backhost + " " + backport);
    try {
        OutputStream buffer= new BufferedOutputStream(backsock.getOutputStream());
        buffer.write(msg.getBytes());
        buffer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (true) { }
}
```

}

The connection is established and `Outputstream` inside the `Socket_connect` class will write "I am here !!!" to the server . but when i try to execute another write procces with New `Outputstream` defined inside main i get an error in the line 
`OutputStream buffer= new BufferedOutputStream(backsock.getOutputStream());`
it seems that the backsocket which i defined inside the main file is null .
even though i used `backsock = sc.getSocket();` to make it the same socket i defined inside the instance sc .
however `gethost()` and `getPort()` works perfectly :

```
backhost = sc.getHost();
backport = sc.getPort();
System.out.println(backhost + " " + backport);
```

this will print the `127.0.0.1 8080`
I can get them back and store them inside int and string defined in main and use `System.out` to print them but I can't get back the `Socket` or outputstream from class. they return `null`.
I used to use C++ and there was a pointer to point at the exact object in a program , but here I can't.

Comment: Unrelated: read about java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCamelCase in java, always. And you dont use "_" in names, unless for SOME_CONSTANT.

Comment: And just for the record: what you are doing there is almost non-sensical. Besides adding ways to not work, using threads here ... really doesnt do anything meaningful. If you want to learn about multi threading: read a good book or tutorial, and follow that. Dont try to invent your own use cases, when your knowledge isnt ready for that.

Comment: @ghostcat i am trying to work java in android , dosent let me use write in main thread , so i have to make 3 threads one for connect two for write and three for read but i need the socket to be the same for all three threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try run this program several time you may find it working, for some cases. It seems that it is a thread related issue. When you are executing, main method may continue execution even before the socket_connect thread start executing `run()` method. get method of  `host` and `port` works because 
 values are already assigned outside of `run()` method. You can simple check it by waiting for few moments into main method using `Thread.sleep()`.
Example:

```
...
int backport;
String msg ="Second Hi!!!!!";
socket_connect sc = new socket_connect("127.0.0.1",8080);
// add try catch or throw 
// by this time hopefully the socket_connect will start.
Thread.sleep(1000);
backsock = sc.getSocket();
backhost = sc.getHost();
backport = sc.getPort();
System.out.println(backhost + " " + backport);
```

**Note**: also waiting indefinitely `while(true)` is not a good practice. All you can do is to try read something from sockets input stream.

Comment: YES YES YES , thank you , i needed to make the main thread sleep , it seems i needed a delay to make the time for connection to be connected then get the output in the main Thread

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you try to get Socket before it get created. you should integrate thread synchronization technique into your code something like this.

```
public class socket_connect extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    private OutputStream out;
    private String host;
    private int port;
    private Semaphore sema = new Semaphore(1);

    socket_connect(String host, int port) {
        try {
            this.host = host;
            this.port = port;
            this.sema.acquire();
            this.start();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            this.socket = new Socket(this.host, this.port);
            this.out = new BufferedOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
            this.out.write("i am here \n\r".getBytes());
            this.out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sema.release();
        }
    }

    public int getPort() throws InterruptedException {
            return port;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public Socket getSocket() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            sema.acquire();
            return socket;
        } finally {
            sema.release();
        }
    }

    public OutputStream getOut() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            sema.acquire();
            return out;
        }finally {
            sema.release();
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            Socket backsock;
            String backhost;
            int backport;
            String msg = "Second Hi!!!!!";
            socket_connect sc = new socket_connect("google.com", 80);
            backsock = sc.getSocket();
            backhost = sc.getHost();
            backport = sc.getPort();
            System.out.println(backhost + " " + backport);
            try {
                OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(backsock.getOutputStream());
                buffer.write(msg.getBytes());
                buffer.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: dorod . merci hadi jan , felan ba gozahstane ye delay toye main moshkelo hal kardam , in chizi ke shoma neveshtiym bayad test konam